# “Bad blood” usage

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions

I know that the *bad blood* expression means animosity and dislike. But where does it come from? I can understand why *bad*, but why *blood*, and whose blood is implied here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it comes from “blood feuds” between families, clans, or tribes. Have a look at [Wiktionary’s definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bad_blood). One of the earliest appearances seems to be in *Essays of Elia* by Charles Lamb in 1823.